# Node + PostgreSQL - is this a valid way to execute transactions?

Tags: node.js, node-postgres

I have an api built on Nodejs that uses [node_postgres](https://node-postgres.com/).

The website says: `...if you initialize or use transactions with the pool.query method you will have problems.`

Im using `pool.query` where I don't need transactions. But I'm creating a client and releasing it everytime I need transactions. I'm wondering if this is a valid way to execute transactions, and if it is sufficient to release the client instead of ending it, so I dont end up with something like concurrency or leaks.

Their recommended way to execute transactions is:

```
const client = await pool.connect()
 
try {
  await client.query('BEGIN')
  const queryText = 'INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES($1) RETURNING id'
  const res = await client.query(queryText, ['brianc'])
 
  const insertPhotoText = 'INSERT INTO photos(user_id, photo_url) VALUES ($1, $2)'
  const insertPhotoValues = [res.rows[0].id, 's3.bucket.foo']
  await client.query(insertPhotoText, insertPhotoValues)
  await client.query('COMMIT')
} catch (e) {
  await client.query('ROLLBACK')
  throw e
} finally {
  client.release()
}
```

So, I created a file that exports Pool:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')
require('dotenv').config()

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    databaseName = 'dev_db'
} else if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    databaseName = 'prod_db'
} 

const connectionString = `postgresql://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.DB_HOST}/${databaseName}`
const connectionStringProd = `postgresql://${process.env.DB_USER_PROD}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD_PROD}@${process.env.DB_HOST_PROD}/${process.env.DB_NAME_PROD}`

const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: isProduction ? connectionStringProd : connectionString
})

module.exports = pool
```

Then, when I don't need transactions I use:

```
app.get('/api/users', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const users = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM users')
        return res.status(201).send({users: users.rows})
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).send({status: 500, error: error})
    }
})
```

And when I do need transactions:

```
 app.post('/api/test', async (req, res) => {
    const client = await pool.connect()
    try {           
        await client.query('BEGIN')
        const {some_value, another_value} = req.body                     

        await client.query('INSERT INTO some_table(some_value) VALUES ($1)', [some_value])
        await client.query('INSERT INTO some_other_table (another_value) VALUES ($1)', [another_value])
       
        await client.query('COMMIT')
        return res.status(201).send('ok')


    } catch (error) {
        await client.query('ROLLBACK')
        return res.status(500).send({status: 500, error: error})
    } finally {
        client.release()
    }
})
```

Since everytime I need transaction I'm calling `const client = await pool.connect()`, and ending with `client.release()`, Im not sure if Im managing the clients correctly.

Is this a valid approach? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes every time you need transaction, you need to lock 1 connection from the pool with pool.connect() and then release it with client.release().
The idea behind is that transaction should be done with same db connection. When you use pool generally, it gives you 1 of the free connections available in the pool and each query executes with different connection, that is why you are not locking connection in separate query situations.
Also releasing is extremely important. If you hold 1 connection from the pool, it will still be held even after transaction is done, since you manually requested connection. This way you will hold up all your connections in the pool and database will be blocked. When you perform normal query from the pool, it automatically releases connection for you.